# How to extract vector filename from .ai files

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, eps

I have a lot of *.ai* files. Each *.ai* file contains a lot of vectors, each vector comes as a file (eps/ai) which has been downloaded from Shutterstock-like websites.

We've lost all these eps/ai vector files (both HDDs died), but we still have a back-up of all finalized projects under different formats: .ai, .pdf and .indd packages.

**Is there any way to get a vector's original filename?**

**TL;DR**
• A lot of files which contain 1 vector (546546844132.eps) - all lost
• A lot of projects (books, banners - ai, pdf, indd packages) where we have used these vectors - we still have them!
• How can we extract the original filename for each vector from these final   projects?

Any input, feedback, or lead is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.idd` is actually `.indd` - the native InDesign format? Then you can see the original file names in the Links panel, although InDesign may complain the original files are missing.

Comment: I don't really understand what's being asked here. A file titled 546546844132.eps has that as it's name. Are you asking if there's internal meta data which tracks *every* name the file may have ever had?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about design.

Comment: @Jongware: I have renamed .idd to to .indd

Comment: @Scott: I am asking if I can find out the original file name of each vector from an ai/pdf page or InDesign package. Something like metadata pointing to the original 4864314862.eps